# Now you're thinking with parameters; Having a NOT list as a parameter option (report builder 3.0)

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have been super impressed with the way you guys think about parameters in SSRS. You can make them do all sorts of interesting things. I have a report where I want two parameter options reflected in my SQL query, option one is as list of numbers for a certain field. This is easily done via

```
WHERE [DDI] in @DDI
```

Setting up the parameter DDI to include the full list of numbers. The point I'm struggling is with the counter case. In essence I need the query to become

```
WHERE [DDI] not in @DDI
```

If the second option is picked. I think the best way to solve this is with nested parameters but I can't think with portals sorry parameters in the correct way to figure this out.

TLDR : I want a parameter solution where user can pick between 2 options the first gives them a curated list in a particular field and the second gives everything **except** that curated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a drop down parameter with Include (YES), Exclude (NO) wording.  Then in your stored procedure it could filter based on the value passed

```
WHERE (( @Include = 'YES' AND [DDI] in @DDI) OR (@Include = 'NO' AND [DDI] NOT IN @DDI))

``
```